# Use mixin argument as variable

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

So i have different variables and want to generate css depending on the argument ( **which is also a variable** ) i give.

I want to use the given argument as a variable name. F.e. when given primary as an argument i actually want to get the value of the variable $primary-brighter.

For example:

```
$primary: #f5f5f5;
$primary-brighter: #fff;

$secondary: #000;
$secondary-brighter: #333;
```

Mixin:

```
@mixin button-style($argument) {

 background: $argument
 color: $argument-brighter
}
```

In use:

```
.button-primary {
 @include button-style(primary)
}
```

What i expect to get:

```
.button-primary {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 color: #fff
}
```

What i get:

```
Error or
.button-primary {
 background: primary-brighter
}
```

Do i need to escape the argument to use it as a variable? ? 
Or is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a cleaner way, but you could achieve something like this with [maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps). One way would be to define your button classes as keys of a map that hold another map of the actual colors to be used:

```
$button-colors: (

  "primary": (
    background: #f5f5f5,
    color: #fff
  ),

  "secondary": (
    background: #000,
    color: #333
  )

);
```

Then in your mixin your  `$argument` would be a text value instead of a hex value and you could access the button color map:

```
@mixin button-style($argument) {

  $color-map: map-get($button-colors, $argument);

  background: map-get($color-map, background);
  color: map-get($color-map, color);

}
```

The mixin would then be consumed like this:

```
.button-primary {
 @include button-style(primary)
}

.button-secondary {
 @include button-style(secondary)
}
```

Comment: @Evolis for some reason I didn't think about the variable being passed in as a hex value, so that makes sense. Unfortunately that approach wouldn't work then. I updated my answer with an approach using maps. It works, but it's not quite as clean.